# Why i see RCX register in my Ubuntu, but the tutorial im watching shows a register called ECX?

Tags: gdb

I'm watching a tutorial about debugging an executable, he is using **gdb-peda** and I'm using **gdb** from Ubuntu 19.10 for debug, i was confused for a moment because i thought it would be a problem if i can't find a register with the exact same name, anyway i continued with the debugging learning, but now i have a doubt: **What is the reason his registers differs from mine?**

**His registers:**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFATS.png)

**My registers:**

```
        (gdb) info registers
    rax            0x7fffffffddc0      140737488346560
    rbx            0x0                 0
    rcx            0x414141            4276545
    rdx            0x4                 4
    rsi            0x7fffffffe299      140737488347801
    rdi            0x7fffffffddc0      140737488346560
    rbp            0x7fffffffddf0      0x7fffffffddf0
    rsp            0x7fffffffdda0      0x7fffffffdda0
    r8             0x0                 0
    r9             0x7ffff7fe11f0      140737354011120
    r10            0x0                 0
    r11            0x0                 0
    r12            0x5555555550e0      93824992235744
    r13            0x7fffffffded0      140737488346832
    r14            0x0                 0
    r15            0x0                 0
    rip            0x555555555228      0x555555555228 <main+95>
    eflags         0x246               [ PF ZF IF ]
    cs             0x33                51
    ss             0x2b                43
    ds             0x0                 0
    es             0x0                 0
    fs             0x0                 0
    gs             0x0                 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compiled your code for a 64-bit target machine, so you are seeing 64-bit registers. To use 32-bit registers, as ECX, you must compile your code with the -m32 flag.